# Pixelated Banners in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am having trouble with the banners on this Drupal Site (www.ciob.org.uk) The static banners are somewhat pixelated when viewed in the front end. In the back end they are listed and shown as they would appear. These seem fine and have no pixelation.

I also have an issue where the banner is 700x230 on the image info yet when I have uploaded an image it cuts 30 pixels off the right side.

Any help on either of these issues would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Imagecache to process your images. ImageCache will resize all images to the dimensions that are configured in his preset. For your case, 700*230

This is your image proccessed with imagecache : http://www.ciob.org.uk/sites/ciob.org.uk/files/imagecache/700x230sc/images/Skills%20Survey%202011%20Banner_1.jpg

This is the image you uploaded : http://www.ciob.org.uk/sites/ciob.org.uk/files/images/Skills%20Survey%202011%20Banner_1.jpg

Th original image is 680*230 pixel, and imagecache will upscale it to 700 pixel wide, that's also why you loose some content on the right.

You can either :

- Use an Original image with correct
  dimension (700*230)
- Don't allow
  imagecache to upscale images (there
  is an option for that), but you will
  probably some blank area in the
  banner, on the front page.

Comment: Thanks for this, this image was reduced in width because of the auto cropping issue i was having. the red one fore example is a full length, you will notice that part of the guys hand is missing.